# Limit substitutions to first n instances per line in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, hash, replace

I have a similar situation to Stack Overflow post *[Substituting array elements from one tab delimited file with hash values from another file using Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863313/substituting-array-elements-from-one-tab-delimited-file-with-hash-values-from-an)*. I am trying to replace a string that matches hash keys by their respective values in specific columns.

```
    Given the @array:

    a b abbd
    cc d abcd
    gg hh cdag

and the %hash:

$VAR1 = {
    'a'  => 'GAT_1',
    'b'  => 'GAT_2',
    'cc' => 'GAT_3',
    'd'  => 'GAT_4',
    'gg' => 'GAT_5',
    'hh' => 'GAT_6',
};
```

I've tried this code, but it doesn't work. How can I limit the replacement of only the first two instances (columns) of the matching keys?
(that is, leaving the third column unchanged?)

```
foreach $line (@array) {
    my @cols = split (/\s+/, $line);
    $cols[0] = $hash{cols[0]};
    $cols[1] = $hash{cols[1]};
    push @newarray, $line;
}


Expected output:
GAT_1 GAT_2 abbd
GAT_3 GAT_4 abcd
GAT_5 GAT_6 cdag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join the columns after the substitutions:

```
my $line_after_lookup;
foreach $line (@array) {
    my @cols = split (/\s+/, $line);

    if (defined($$VAR1{$cols[0]})) { $cols[0] = $$VAR1{$cols[0]}; }    
    if (defined($$VAR1{$cols[1]})) { $cols[1] = $$VAR1{$cols[1]}; } 

    #
    # When using a hash instead of a hash reference, replace the previous 2 statements with the following 2 lines:
    # if (defined($hash{$cols[0]})) { $cols[0] = $hash{$cols[0]}; }
    # if (defined($hash{$cols[1]})) { $cols[1] = $hash{$cols[1]}; }
    #

    $line_after_lookup = join ( ' ', @cols );
    push @newarray, $line_after_lookup ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this, but I'm getting references instead of the hash values when I print the output. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: always `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

Comment: @stevieb sure. the  answer contains only a code excerpt, the statements you mention would go at the beginning of the package or script.

Comment: @cmvdi01 Sorry for the glitch, I used the wrong variable name. Code corrected.

Comment: Do you really mean "{cols[0]}" and "{cols[1]}"? (Not "{$cols[0]}" and "{$cols[1]}"?)

Comment: @PeterMortensen You are right of course, another typo (sigh). Thanks for pointing that one out.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I'm still getting the references when I use ` if (defined ($hash{$cols[0]})) { $cols[0] = $hash{$cols[0]}; } ` and when I use: ` if (defined ($$hash{$cols[0]})) { $cols[0] = $$hash{$cols[0]}; } ` I get a warning: "Global symbol "$hash" requires explicit package name at..."

Comment: @cmvdi01 You are referring to a hash _variable_ `%hash` while your original code uses the hash _reference_ `$VAR1` ( 1 additional layer of indirection). The correct code lines for using `%hash` are thus  `if (defined($hash{$cols[0]})) { $cols[0] = $hash{$cols[0]}; }` and its counterpart `if (defined($hash{$cols[1]})) { $cols[1] = $hash{$cols[1]}; }`.

Comment: @collapsar I've mentioned %hash in my original code as well, that's probably why it got confusing, sorry. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper; 

my %substitute = (
    'a'  => 'GAT_1',
    'b'  => 'GAT_2',
    'cc' => 'GAT_3',
    'd'  => 'GAT_4',
    'gg' => 'GAT_5',
    'hh' => 'GAT_6',
);

my @newarray;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @fields = split;
    $fields[0] = $substitute{ $fields[0] };
    $fields[1] = $substitute{ $fields[1] };
    push ( @newarray, join( " ", @fields ));
}

print Dumper \@newarray;

__DATA__
    a b abbd
    cc d abcd
    gg hh cdag
```

Prints:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'GAT_1 GAT_2 abbd',
          'GAT_3 GAT_4 abcd',
          'GAT_5 GAT_6 cdag'
        ];
```

Yours isn't working because you're changing the contents of `@fields` not `$line`. However another possible gotcha is your split - `split /\s+/` handles leading whitespace differently (you get an empty field).

Comment: Your code works fine when I'm reading directly from the file, but it doesn't work with the array where my data are stored (@array). Any alternatives to replace `while (<IN>)` by `foreach $line (@array)´? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that. I wanted to make sure my example was runnable. Note, the above breaks if there is no hash element to look up.

Comment: Just bear in mind that split acts implicitly on $_ by default.  So you can do `foreach (@lines) { my @fields = split ;... `

Answer (score 0):

*How can I limit the replacement of only the first two instances (columns) of the matching keys? (i.e. leaving the third column unchanged?)*

One way would be to use a regular expression that picks off just those two columns and performs the appropriate substitutions.

Illustration (edited):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @array = (
    "a b abbd",
    "cc d abcd",
    "gg hh cdag",
    "ii jj kmln"  # to show what happens when no mapping exists 
);

my %hash = (
'a' => 'GAT_1',
'b' => 'GAT_2',
'cc' => 'GAT_3',
'd' => 'GAT_4',
'gg' => 'GAT_5',
'hh' => 'GAT_6',
);

sub replace { $hash{$_[0]} || $_[0]; } # original string if no mapped value

sub convert { replace($_[0]) . $_[1] . replace($_[2]); }

my @newarray = map
{
    my $line = $_;
    $line =~ s/(\w+)(\W+)(\w+)/convert($1, $2, $3)/e;
    $line;
} @array;

print "$_\n" for @newarray;
```

The needed substitutions occur here:

```
    $line =~ s/(\w+)(\W+)(\w+)/convert($1, $2, $3)/e;
```

The `e` modifier on the `s///` expression causes the replacement expression in the second part to be evaluated, so that sub convert() is called.  The arguments to convert() come from the captures in the regular expression of the first part: `(\w+)` to capture the first sequence of word characters, `(\W+)` to capture non-word characters such as white space or punctuation, and `(\w+)` again to capture the second sequence of word characters.  The rest of the line being irrelevant need not be parsed at all and is left as is.

You may also need to think about what happens if a mapped value isn't available.  The code above leaves the original strings intact in such cases.

Comment: The subroutines replace() and convert() should be easy to figure out.  The key operation is the s///e substitution expression.  The `e` modifier causes the second part of the s/// to be evaluated (so that convert() gets called).  The 3 arguments come from the first part: `\b` for a word boundary, `(\w+)` to capture word characters, `(\W+)` to capture non-word characters, i.e. spaces, punctuation, etc, and then `(\w+)` again to capture the second sequence of word characters.   There is no need to split or parse the entire line.

Comment: @arayq2: It is better if you edit the explanation into your answer.